# Magento 2: upgrade to 2.1.6 resulted product images not working

Tags: cache, product-images, magento2.1.6

I upgraded Magento 2.1.5 to 2.1.6 and after upgrade the product images in frontend's product list pages stopped working. Inspect says the following for all the products:

GET /pub/media/catalog/product/cache/f073062f50e48eb0f0998593e568d857/t/r/image.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Tried to clear and disable cache. I also re-deployed static content. Also set the owner of pub/media to be apache user.

Also worth noting that images at product pages work without a problem. The problem is at the product list page.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to run this command:

```
php magento catalog:images:resize
```

They have changed the way the the images are resized in 2.1.6 and running that is needed.

Comment: FYI - If you have **hidden/disabled images**, this command alone will not regenerate them.  If you have a large number of products, consider a quick core change to the file below, run the resize function above, then remove the core change below you just made.
`/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php`
_(line 1471, comment out "continue;" in foreach() of getMediaGalleryImages())_